# Is there a simple class that encapsulates a Boolean and a String?

Tags: java

It is so common in UI logic that you have a method to `checkValid(something)`.  Its primary use is to return a `Boolean`.  But in case of invalid (or `false`), we may want to provide an additional user message about what is being invalid, after all the `checkValid()` method might have checked 20 different things. By simply responding with "not valid" to the user is not very helpful.

So is there a built-in Java class or some from Apache commons that does just that?  I understand it is so simple to build my own, but my sense tells me this is so common I must missed it somewhere in common packages.

Comment: In homemade software: convection "nothing happens, is OK" (silent scenario), and "wrong data - exception with details". But this depends on framework

Comment: In genelar, JSR 303 and probably others give direction for more professional software

Comment: in C mood: return NULL, no problem, else return String with description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Status codes have long been used to return "Success" (often 0) or "Failure" responses, with failures further identified by distinct non-zero values.  The `Enum` class is a friendlier way of doing this.

```
enum Status { 
    SUCCESS("Success"), 
    BAD_PATH("The directory does not contain the required file"),
    HAS_THE_LETTER_C("The directory must not contain the letter C");

    private final String message;
    private Status(String _message) {
        message = _message;
    };

    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        return message;
    }
}
```

---

```
Status status = checkValid(something);
if (status != Status.SUCCESS) {
   // Inform user of specific failure reason
}
```

Comment: Hm... that is a good thought!  But I would like a very descriptive error message like "The directory path you provided does not contain file foo".  I guess I will need to build my own message map using the enum.  I can live with that.  Thanks!

Comment: return codes in OOP have in genaral bad opinion (has procedural smell), agree with @Michael , sometimes can be good

Comment: Enums can be customized to include descriptive messages - I'll edit.

Comment: natural only fixed, compiled strings. This no long term solution

Comment: I saw edited version too: Do You feel, how limited is this solution? What with new validation situation?

Comment: Having well defined `Enum` values for different error conditions lends itself to internationalization as well.  The messages associated with the different values may be looked up from a message bundle.    Unfortunately, the `Enum` cannot be extended by a derived `Enum` to add additional error codes; all possible errors must be defined in the original `Enum`.

Answer (score 1):

Apache commons has a [`Pair`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) class, so you could use a `Pair<Boolean, String>`. Alternatively, you could just return a `String` with the validation failure, and treat a `null` as non-error (i.e., the validation either returns the reason of a failure or `null` if there's no failure).

Comment: Pair is quite generic.  I was looking for more of something like: BooleanAndMessage.isTrue(), BooleanAndMessage.getMessage() object.  I can't think of a good name yet.